# How to remove strings like los30_9_ from the second column of data file?

Tags: linux, bash

I have data like the following in a file.

```
          seq
AB      los30_9_AAACCTGAGATGTGGC
CGD     los28_6_AAACCTGCAGCTTCGG
CGD     los28_3_AAACCTGCATAGTAAG
CRG     mgj28_3_AAACCTGCATATACGC
CGD     lkgd28_11_AAACCTGGTCTTCTCG
CRG     lkgd28_3_AAACCTGTCAGTTGAC
AB      lkgd35_5_AAACCTGTCTGGTATG
CD      los30_9_AAACGGGCAACCGCCA
CD      lkgd_8_AAACGGGGTTACCAGT**
```

How can I remove `los30_9_`, `los28_6`, `los28_3_`, `mgj28_3_`, `lkgd28_11_`, `lkgd28_3_`, `lkgd28_3_`, `lkgd35_5_`, `los30_9_`, `lkgd_8_` from the second column of a CSV file?

Comment: Try `sed -r 's/([[:alnum:]]+[[:space:]]*)(.*_)(.*)/\1\3/' <your_file>`.

Comment: @sungtm Here, I found an error in the output file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Python 3 solution will do, as well as it will respect multiline fields on the csv file.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

import csv
import re

csvr = csv.reader(open('input.csv'), delimiter = "\t")
next(csvr, None)

for row in csvr:
    row[1] = re.sub(r'[a-z0-9]+_[a-z0-9]+_', '', row[1])
    print("{}\t{}".format(row[0],row[1]))
```

Note : Please correct your csv so it contains tabs instead of spaces for this to work. You can open it in Excel and "Save as...".

Comment: That error means your file's name is not **input.csv**. Correct the name for whatever your file is called.

Comment: Hej, Thanks Matias, could you explain the code a bit. Example from the for row in csvr:                                                                                                              ./code.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./code.py", line 10, in <module>
    row[1] = re.sub(r'[a-z0-9]+_[a-z0-9]+_', '', row[1])
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @Jay That means that its parsing the rows as having one column instead of two. You need to change the spacing between each column from "a lot of spaces" to a single tab **or** save it with excel so it has *commas* instead and change the **delimiter="\t"** in the code to **delimiter=","**